# Get Folder Path Synchronously from FutureAccessList

Tags: c++, .net, uwp

I have a number of folders stored in the FutureAccessList using a FolderPicker. For logging/configuration purposes I would like to be able to enumerate these and print out their full path as a String.

I have written the code below to try and help with this, but it keeps throwing the following:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0355CAB6 (ucrtbased.dll) in foo.exe: An invalid 
parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

Here is the code, if anyone could tell me where I am going wrong I would appreciate it. Really I want to execute the GetFolderAsync function in a synchronous manner, i.e. exec-wait-return. I'm sure there's a simple answer but I'm just coming up to speed with C++/UWP programming having backgrounds in other languages!

```
String^ MainPage::GetFolderPathForKey(String^ key)
{
    task<String^> t = create_task(
        StorageApplicationPermissions::FutureAccessList->GetFolderAsync(key))
        .then([](StorageFolder^ folder)
    {
        if (folder != nullptr) {
            return folder->Name;
        }
        return ref new String(L"Unknown?");

    });
    String^ taskResult = t.get();
    return taskResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to attempting the get()/wait() in the UI thread.